# What is the best way to rehydrate aggregate roots and their associated entities in an event sourced environment

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing, aggregateroot

I have seen information on rehydrating aggregate roots in SO, but I am posting this question because I did not find any information in SO about doing so with in the context of an event sourced framework.

Has a best practice been discovered or developed for how to rehydrate aggregate roots when operating on the command side of an application using the event sourcing and CQRS pattern

OR is this still more of a “preference“ among architects?

I have read through a number of blogs and watched a number of conference presentations on you tube  and I seem to get different guidance depending on who I am attending to.

On the one hand, I have found information stating fairly clearly that developers should create aggregates to hydrate themselves using “apply“ methods on events obtained directly from the event store..

On the other hand, I have also seen in several places where presenters and bloggers have recommended rehydrating aggregate roots by submitting a query to the read side of the application. Some have suggested creating specific validation “buckets“ / projections on the read side to facilitate this.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction on discovering if there is a single best practice or if the answer primarily depends upon performance issues or some other issue I am not thinking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hydrating Aggregates in an event sourced framework is a well-understood problem.

> On the one hand, I have found information stating fairly clearly that
>   developers should create aggregates to hydrate themselves using
>   “apply“ methods on events obtained directly from the event store..

This is the prescribed way of handling it. There are various ways of achieving this, but I would suggest keeping any persistence logic (reading or writing events) outside of your Aggregate. One simple way is to expose a constructor that accepts domain events and then applies those events.

> On the other hand, I have also seen in several places where presenters
>   and bloggers have recommended rehydrating aggregate roots by
>   submitting a query to the read side of the application. Some have
>   suggested creating specific validation “buckets“ / projections on the
>   read side to facilitate this.

You can use the concept of snapshots as a way of optimizing your reads. This will create a memoized version of your hydrated Aggregate. You can load this snapshot and then only apply events that were generated since the snapshot was created. In this case, your Aggregate can define a constructor that takes two parameters: an existing state (snapshot) and any remaining domain events that can then be applied to that snapshot.

Snapshots are just an optimization and should be considered as such. You can create a system that does not use snapshots and apply them once read performance becomes a bottleneck.

> On the other hand, I have also seen in several places where presenters
>   and bloggers have recommended rehydrating aggregate roots by
>   submitting a query to the read side of the application

Snapshots are not really part of the read side of the application. Data on the read side exists to satisfy use cases within the application. Those can change based on requirements even if the underlying domain does not change. As such, you shouldn't use read side data in your domain at all.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback!  Do you have any good references for the information you provided (from authoritative sources, etc)? Again, thanks tons!

Comment: While I don't completely agree with his technical approach, I have found Daniel Whitaker's blog to be helpful as another viewpoint into CQRS. Here is a specific post that might be useful. https://danielwhittaker.me/2014/11/15/aggregate-root-cqrs-event-sourcing/

Comment: If you haven't read through the resources at CQRS.NU then I would suggest doing so. Here is the FAQ: http://cqrs.nu/Faq.

Comment: Cperson: thanks tons again!  I’ll be reviewing these both ASAP

Comment: @PatrickWood what does it mean to hydrate an aggregate?

Comment: @Ali.Rashidi  Basically, it just means to instantiate an empty version of the aggregate root and then query the event store for all events related to that particular aggregate root and then apply those events to the state of that object.

Answer (score 0):

Event sourcing has developed different styles over the years. I could divide all o those into two big categories:

- an event stream represents one entity (an aggregate in case of DDD)
- one (partitioned) event stream for a (sub)system

When you deal with one stream per (sub)system, you aren't able to rehydrate the write-side on the fly, it is physically impossible due to the number of events in that stream. Therefore, you would rely on the projected read-side to retrieve the current entity state. As a consequence, this read-side must be fully consistent.

When going with the DDD-flavoured event sourcing, there's a strong consensus in the community how it should be done. The state of the aggregate (not just the root, but the whole aggregate) is restored by the command side before calling the domain model. You always restore using events. When snapshotting is enabled, snapshots are also stored as events in the aggregate snapshot stream, so you read the last one and all events from the snapshot version.

Concerning the `Apply` thing. You need to clearly separate the function that adds new events to the changes list (what you're going to save) and functions what mutate the aggregate state when events are applied.

The first function is the one called `Apply` and the second one is often called `When`. So you call the `Apply` function in your aggregate code to build up the changelist. The `When` function is called when restoring the aggregate state from events when you read the stream, and also from the `Apply` function.

You can find a simplistic example of an event-sourced aggregate in my book repo: https://github.com/alexeyzimarev/ddd-book/blob/master/chapter13/src/Marketplace.Ads.Domain/ClassifiedAds/ClassifiedAd.cs

For example:

```
    public void Publish(UserId userId)
        => Apply(
            new V1.ClassifiedAdPublished
            {
                Id = Id,
                ApprovedBy = userId,
                OwnerId = OwnerId,
                PublishedAt = DateTimeOffset.Now
            }
        );
```

And for the `When`:

```
    protected override void When(object @event)
    {
        switch (@event)
        {
            // more code here

            case V1.ClassifiedAdPublished e:
                ApprovedBy = UserId.FromGuid(e.ApprovedBy);
                State = ClassifiedAdState.Active;
                break;

            // and more here
         }
     }
```